# How use Slide Image When I am click Left and right Button?

Tags: jquery, css

1. LeftMove **lareImage** and **smallimage** is **active** when i am click **leftButton**
2. RightMove **LargeImage** and **smallimage** is **active** when i am click **rightButton**

   How use Jquery and javascript help me advice...

   ```
   <div class="largethumb">
     <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
     <a class="left" href="#"> Left </a>
     <a class="right" href="#"> right </a> 
    </div>  <!-- End largeImage -->

    <div class="thumbgallery clearfix">

      <div class="thumb active">
        <a href="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg">
          <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg"/>
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="thumb">
       <a href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-android.png">
           <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-android.png"/>
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="thumb">
        <a href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-android.png">
           <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-android.png"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb">
         <a href="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg">
           <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
        </a>
       </div>

     </div> <!-- End thumbgallery -->
   ```

jquery

```
   $(".thumbgallery .thumb a").click(function(e) {
     $(this).parents('.thumb').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     $(".largethumb img").attr("src",href);
     e.preventDefault();
    return false;
   });

  $(".largethumb a.left").click(function(){
       <!-- how use laregimage move and smallimage is active -->
  });
   $(".largethumb a.right").click(function(){
     <!-- how use laregimage move and smallimage is active -->
   });
```

## [SEEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/Qc6gL/)

Comment: There are plenty of scripts ready made for this. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: yes my frends. i mean largethumb img src chage slide when a.left click and a.right click chage largeimage.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this could be done by CSS3 also, why using jquery for it...

```
.thumbgallery { }
.thumbgallery .thumb { /* Code For left*/ }
.thumbgallery .thumb:nth-child(odd) { /* Code For right*/ }
```

Hope this idea may work for you.....

Comment: oh my friends , i want jquery control.

Comment: please upadte you answer